# Link Boost with Qt Creator on Mac

Tags: c++, qt

I have installed boost using Homebrew and got everything set up in my .pro file.

myProFile

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
    src/nmea-tests.cpp \
    src/position.cpp \
    src/utilities.cpp \
    src/parsenmea.cpp

HEADERS += \
    headers/parseNMEA.h \
    headers/position.h \
    headers/types.h \
    headers/utilities.h

INCLUDEPATH += headers/

LIBS += -lboost_unit_test_framework

macx {

QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++

LIBS += -L"/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0/lib" -lboost_random

INCLUDEPATH += "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0/include"

}
```

However, when I try to build the project, Qt can't find `boost/test/unit_test.hpp` file

Compiler Error Message:

```
/Users/hadyfarhat/Documents/ntu/courses/soft/task4/gps/src/nmea-tests.cpp:3: error: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Could you post the complete compiler error message? Your words *Qt can't find boost/test/unit_test.hpp file* bring no information at all.

Comment: homebrew installed the version 1.66.0 for me. Are you shure that you installed the version 1.63.0? Look at the output of `brew info boost`.

Comment: @S.M. This was it! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change boost version from `1.63.0` to `1.66.0`.
For Future problems with boost use my question as a guide and be sure to install homebrew before that.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the better way is using `/usr/local/opt/boost` for Intel and `/opt/homebrew/opt/boost` for Apple Silicon in your case. Then you don't need to worry about the problem of the version.